# Swift Code - Multiple PickerViews

Tags: uipickerview

I have placed 2 separate PickerViews in my code. The first PickerView displays the data to initially chose from.

The 2nd PickerView is Hidden behind the First one and its data population will depend upon what was chosen on the First PickerView.

Once the 1st PikerView selection is made, the user taps a "Next" Button. This results in Hiding the 1st PickerView and showing the 2nd PickerView.

I can pick the data on the 1st Picker and hide it, but the second PickerView only displays as an empty space with the PickerView "Selection" line visible. None of the PickerView attributes or data is present.

I am using Swift 2 and am a newbie. Very simple explanations are greatly appreciated! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to figure out how to populate a second PickerView dependent upon what was chosen in the first one.

I have been all over the web and have not been able to find simple code and an explanation that I could understand.

I took it several steps further and add answered so other frequent questions I have seen.

1) How do I pass an Array into the picker when I'm not sure what the first selection is going to be?

2) How do I change the picker background color?

3) I do I change the picker Font, Font size, Font color?

4) How do I get the first item to show up inside a label without having to move the selector and come back to the item?

**So Here It Is !**

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

// Create the Outlets

```
@IBOutlet weak var fruitPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var typePicker: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet weak var fruitPickerButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var subFruitButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var fruitType: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var typeType: UILabel!


// Populate the Arrays

var fruit = ["Apple", "Orange", "Melon"]
var apples = ["MacIntosh", "Gala", "Honey Crisp", "Winesap"]
var oranges = ["Navel", "Blood", "Mandarin", "Valencia"]
var melons = ["Cantaloupe", "Honeydew", "Watermelon", "Casaba"]

var selectedArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Set the Delegate for the Pickers

    self.fruitPicker.delegate = self
    self.fruitPicker.dataSource = self

    self.typePicker.delegate = self
    self.typePicker.dataSource = self

    fruitPickerButton.awakeFromNib()

}
```

// PickerView Code

```
// To Specify the Color Font Family and Size of your PickerView Fonts

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView
{
    var pickerLabel = UILabel()

    if pickerView == fruitPicker {
        pickerLabel.text = fruit[row]

        // Text Color

        pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        // Font Family and Size

        pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Chalkboard SE", size: 20)

        // Text Alignment within the PickerView

        pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

        // PickerView Background Color

        pickerLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 0.5, saturation: 0.8, brightness:0.7, alpha: 0.5)

        // Draw the Label

        return pickerLabel

    } else if pickerView == typePicker {

        pickerLabel.text = selectedArray[row] as! String}
        pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Chalkboard SE", size: 20)
        pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        pickerLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 0.9, saturation: 0.8, brightness:0.7, alpha: 0.5)

        return pickerLabel

}

// Number of Columns in each PickerView

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1

}

// Number of Rows in each PickerView

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int  {

    if pickerView == fruitPicker {

    return fruit.count

    } else if pickerView == typePicker {

        return selectedArray.count

    }

    return 0
}

// Custom Height for each PickerView Row

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView,
    rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 45
}

// Assign Labels to each individual PickerView Row

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) ->  String?  {

    if pickerView == fruitPicker {

        return fruit[row]

    } else if pickerView == typePicker {

        return selectedArray[row] as! String

    }

    return nil

}

// Determine which Row on which PickerView is Selected

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if pickerView == fruitPicker {  // If the active PickerView is the fruitPicker do this ...

    switch row { // Check to see which Row is Selected

    case 0:

        selectedArray = apples
        fruitType.text = "Apple"

    case 1:

        selectedArray = oranges
        fruitType.text = "Orange"

    case 2:

        selectedArray = melons
        fruitType.text = "Melon"

    default:
        selectedArray = []
    }

        typePicker.reloadAllComponents()  // VERY IMPORTANT - Reload all of the PickerView Attributes into the typePicker PickerView

        typePicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true) // Reset to first Row and clear the Label Field
        typeType.text = ""

    } else if pickerView == typePicker { // Determine which Array is to be used to fill the typePicker and show the typePickers Row text in the typeType Label

        var item = selectedArray[row]

        if selectedArray == apples {
            typeType.text = item as! String

        } else if selectedArray == oranges {
            typeType.text = item as! String

        } else if selectedArray == melons {
            typeType.text! = item as! String
        }
    }
}

// Used to allow selection of Apple before the FruitPicker has been activated

@IBAction func fruitPickerButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    fruitType.text = "Apple"
    let pickerView = typePicker
    selectedArray = apples
    typePicker.reloadAllComponents()
    fruitPickerButton.hidden = true
}

// Used to allow selection of Macintosh before the TypePicker has been activated

@IBAction func subFruitButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    if selectedArray == apples {
        typeType.text = "MacIntosh"

    } else if selectedArray == oranges {
        typeType.text = "Navel"

    } else if selectedArray == melons {
        typeType.text = "Cantaloupe"


    }
}
```

}